# Possible to enlarge only the Win32 menu font without affecting the rest of the Windows GUI?

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I kind of suspect the answer is "No", but am asking just to make sure, so if you know it is impossible, just tell me so.

What I want to make bigger is the menu font of Win32 applications such as Notepad, etc. This seems to be shared by all native Win32 applications, and the font size is too small to read.

Changing DPI is not an option because the DPI is already high and the title bar is uselessly thick. Also, I have tried a utility but changing the menu font size made other unwanted already-big things huge. I just want to increase the menu font size. Is this possible?

[image]
[image]

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics